# not defined as association in doctrine orm validate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have two entities named UserCode and Question that have relation between question columns and when i run `doctrine:schema:validate` it s ok
but my problem is when i add

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserCodeRepository")
```

at top of UserCode entity i get this error !!

```
* The association AppBundle\Entity\UserCode#question refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Question#question which is not defined as association.
* The association AppBundle\Entity\UserCode#question refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Question#question which does not exist.
```

Question entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\UserCode;


/**
 * Question
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="question")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\QuestionRepository")
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="text")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserCode", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $question;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set question
     *
     * @param string $question
     *
     * @return Question
     */
    public function setQuestion($question)
    {
        $this->question = $question;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get question
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuestion()
    {
        return $this->question;
    }

}
```

and this is my UserCode entity:

```
<?php



namespace AppBundle\Entity;



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;



/**
 * UserCode
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_code")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserCodeRepository")
 */

class UserCode

{

    /**

     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Question", inversedBy="question")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question", referencedColumnName="id")
     */

    private $question;




    /**

     * Get id

     *

     * @return int

     */

    public function getId()

    {

        return $this->id;

    }






    /**

     * Set question

     *

     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Question $question

     *

     * @return UserCode

     */

    public function setQuestion(\AppBundle\Entity\Question $question = null)

    {

        $this->question = $question;



        return $this;

    }



    /**

     * Get question

     *

     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Question

     */

    public function getQuestion()

    {

        return $this->question;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="question", referencedColumnName="id")
```

from
UserCode entity and

```
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="question", type="text")
```

from question entity 
it will work perfectly :)